# Update data displayed after updating database android

Tags: java, android, mobile, parse-platform, auto-update

So I'm developing an android app that interacts with database ( Parse.com ) , the users can edit their profile information. how to get the updated data( auto-refresh) displayed directly after the user save the updates without having to close the app and open it again ..

any suggestion ?

Comment: Not sure what you want, just use the updated data.

Comment: I want to auto refresh my data on my app when updated .

Comment: I bet you can get lots of result when you search this on Google. have you tried that?

Comment: Not sure what you want but search for async thread One of its uses to update views in run time

Comment: Auto-refresh data when I update it .. for example I change my profile picture in the edit page , I want if I get back to my profile I see the new image instead of the old one .. got my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get your data updated after refreshing them, use [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) method.